# vibration activated delay ciruit

Tags: circuit-analysis, troubleshooting

why this circuit doesn't work? I need this circuit to sense vibration, then after some delay, turn on the piezo beeper, and then after some delay, turn it off.

1. Q1 is turned on when vibration is detected, and charge up C1 via R1;
2. after some delay, Q2 will be turned on, and the piezo is beeping;
3. after awhile C1 is discharged via R2, and Q2 will be off.

C2 is used, so when Q2 is on, it will turn off Q1, preventing Q1 from charging C1.

[image]

Comment: You don't just "turn on" a piezo beeper by applying a supply voltage to it like this circuit does. The buzzer works like a loudspeaker, it needs a signal like a 2 kHz squarewave. Try replacing the buzzer with a LED and a resistor and see if the LED is on when you want to hear a beep. Then you could make an oscillator power that with this circuit.

Comment: i am using a piezo with internal oscillator, but I will try it with led any way. thank you

Comment: "why this circuit doesn't work?". My dog is ill, tell me what is wrong with it.

Comment: The delay on doesn't work at all. and delay off seems took forever.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the value of the 1k (on the vibration switch) to 5k or 10k, and increase R1 to 20k or more.  That should slow down the "on" delay.

Then place a high value resistor across C1 to ground, (about 2x or 3x the value of R1). That should quicken up the delay off.

To optimize the resistor values temporarily replace R1 and the new resistor across C1 with 100k potentiometers, adjust till you get the desired delays, then measure the potentiometer values and re-install resistors of that value.  (Just be sure you don't set both potentiometers to zero - cause you'll burn out transistors with just a little delay....)